# Copy Custom Options To Other Products

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, custom-options

I've been fighting with this issue for days now and I can't hold it any longer.

We have Magento Community Edition 1.9 running with a extension from MageWorld Advanced Product Options.

It was an expensive extension which apparently doesn't work properly on 1.9. For days I
ve been trying to copy the product options from one product to multiple because it would save me a lot of time and the extension should automatically support it.

But it doesn't work, isn't it there any easier way to copy custom options from one product to multiple?

Comment: Amasty mass product actions has this function.  Besides this it could be done at the database level.

Comment: I would be all over the developer.  They should be able to help and let you know what needs to be done.  Otherwise, there may be a compatibility issue with another extension.

Comment: Your issue is with a 3rd party extension.  Contact the 3rd party vendor for assistance.

Comment: I use the same module on 1.9.2 - why it is not working - what is the issue can you update your questions with more info

Comment: Easiest thing to do is open the product, then press 'duplicate' this will copy all of the fields including your custom options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running the furniture store and have dozens of options for each product. So I use this [dynamic product options magento extension](https://www.itoris.com/magento-custom-options.html). I just create templates and apply to multiple products.

Answer (score -2):

If you select the items that you would like to edit in Catalog -> Manage Products, click on the dropdown next to "Actions" in the upper right hand corner and select "Update Attributes" it will take you to a page that will allow you to bulk apply Attribute changes to the products selected.

Comment: I fail to see how this answer has any relevance to the question asked.

Comment: This Answer is irrelevant. There is no such option to update 'Custom Options' through Update Attributes feature.